# Is there a way to introduce transparent sentinels before the begin and at the end of std::vector data?

Tags: c++, stl

Some algorithms (like lexicographical search and comparison) could be written shorter without boundary checks for the array, especially when it comes to comparison strings through indexes.

For example:

```cpp
    int offset=0;
    for ( ; index–offset >= 0 && *(&index+line)–offset >= 0 
        && text[index-offset ] == text[*(&index+line)-offset ]; ++offset )
        ;
```

which could be shortened to

```cpp
    int offset=0;
    for ( ;text[index-offset ] == text[*(&index+line)-offset ]; ++offset )
        ;
```

The problem is that there are many such border checks in many places and it makes the code harder to read.

Of course, I can add sentinels in the array, but I want only to make sure that comparison will stop; otherwise I don’t want to see the sentinels in other places. So, I want to have them "transparently".

In case there were any chance to put a *sentinel* (value which couldn't belong to data in the vector) before `begin()` and at the `end()` that could solve the problem. For sure, I understand that this is impossible because of many reasons:

1. With this container should handle negative indexes as input to operator[]
2. Iterators also will be forced to address memory "before array" which is impossible.
3. This breaks the whole idea around iterators, containers, begin() and end()

With this, what would be the most straightforward way to achieve this goal? I am sure that is a common trick in programming, so there should be something to simplify its implementation in language.

Of course, this could be easily solved, involving another level of indirection (another index), but this is too much expensive.

I would use projections/views with ranges, as well, but I need to have execution policies which are not yet implemented for ranges.

Are there some approaches with inheritance, wrapping, substituting still staying with array-like container (preferably, `std::vector`) so that I could leave most of the code untouched?

**Code review and code improvement**
Since most of concerns were related to the task and code themselves, I created Code Review request on SO: [Fast search for the longest repeating substrings in large text](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288936/fast-search-for-the-longest-repeating-substrings-in-large-text). Could you please, participate to clean up the code first and make it utilizing all modern C++ features before we continue considering the original question itself.

Comment: I don't really understand why you need more than the begin and end iterators but perhaps you could store `std::optional`s in your `vector`?

Comment: Seems you are looking for sentinels. The standard ranges library functions all support working with sentinels with different type from iterators. Is `std::ranges::subrange(iter, custom_sentinel)` good enough for you?

Comment: The first example makes no sense to me. Neither `index`, nor `offset`, nor `line` are updated each iteration, only `match`. Why are they part of the loop condition then? This would all likely be a non-issue if you formulated your for loops minimally,and if you normalized them so they use iterators, or classic `for (int i = 0 ...`

Comment: @TedLyngmo, maybe the wording of the question is bad, I will be thankful for any help to improve it. I explained that I need stop-values to avoid checking for array ranges. What is missing here? What is the way to use std::optional here?

Comment: @WeijunZhou, just minutes ago I got a second thought that projections/ranges could solve this problem easily. My problem is that I need execution policies which are not implemented for ranges yet. Updated the question.

Comment: @JanSchultke, if you see offset and line are at different levels of indirection. I don't see a way to "minimize" the first loop. I will be thankful, if you show the way for this particular loop, this will be helpful, as well. (If you like I can create working demo for this). Anyway, this is not the only place where there are such bounding checks and not always code could be "minimized". Although, maybe your example would help to understand how.

Comment: @Slava *"Why downvotes?"* -- I don't know other's reasons, but if this question had a non-negative score, I would be inclined to vote down because it uses code to describe what is going on instead of words. Code is harder to search for and is subject to multiple interpretations. I would classify that as "unclear".

Comment: @DamirTenishev it's trivial to do. `index`, `offset`, and `line` are loop invariants so you can simply pull `index–offset >= 0 && *(&index+line)–offset >= 0` out of the loop condition and into a surrounding if statement. The only thing that changes throughout the loop is `match`. I mean, you've done it yourself. I'm basically confused why this is even an example. Who added those boundary checks and why are they even a problem?

Comment: @Slava, thank you for support. I have to agree, most of time people tend to down-vote questions out of their understanding. Sometimes this is reasonable, though, since the author is responsible for making good questions and foresee what issues will people see. We are all learning here in all ways. BTW, your way to disagree with them is to upvote. :) At the same time I would move this discussion to meta (not providing the link here, since it would cause meta-effect and collect tons of downvotes. A would agree that this particular question is not the best by nature of topic (way too "hacky").

Comment: @PasserBy, I believe, it is better to move this conversation to meta, not referencing to the specific topic. One thing I would agree is that it is really hard to improve questions when this hits come out of dark without any comments like assessment from bad professor in university "guess what I want to hear from you...". Would down-votes have any comments, they would helpful, but here I just to have wild guesses. Anyway, please, let's continue this on meta, if you like.

Comment: @Slava because this question reeks of XY problem. OP is asking about how they can implement a specific solution when it's unclear what causes the problem in the first place, or what the problem actually is. From my POV, the problem is that there are some poorly readable loop conditions. It's entirely unclear whether sentinel values are a good way of solving it.

Comment: @JaMiT, actually in the context of this question, I am interested in how to use transparent sentinels for cases where I have many bounds checks. At the same time I am actually very interested if this code could be significantly improved without sentinels. The code uses suffix arrays to find the longest similar parts in the text and this is a part of the code. I am not sure how can I make in small enough to be readable here and working. If I create a code review question, would you, please, participate? I just want to avoid mess in comments here. Not sure `int match=index` would help here.

Comment: @JanSchultke, damn. My bad. Sorry for the mess (before others as well). When I copied the code from the project, I decided that `match` will be misleading and renamed it to 'offset' and in haste made a mess of the code, renaming only part of them. That's why we need minimal reproducible examples. Thank you. Fixed. Sorry again. Any way to improve this one?

Comment: @JaMiT, yes, thank you for the pinpointing. Sorry, my bad with renaming the match to offset which was done somehow only partially. Fixed. Sorry for the mess. The intention was to make code simpler to read with this last minute renaming on copy to SO. I was focused on the stop-values (sentinels) and missed this somehow.

Comment: @DamirTenishev *"The code uses [X] and this is a part of the code. I am not sure how can I make in small enough to be readable here and working"* -- You have already made the code small enough to be readable. Make your description match. At a guess, the loops demonstrate finding an `offset` that makes certain elements match. If so, your high-level goal is to find `offset`. That would give me enough context to say you should move the code into a function.

Comment: @JaMiT, thank you. I will prepare the demo on godbolt with the text explanation, since I am still really interested both in code, improving approach and the topic. Would it work if I post another question on this here (I prefer this way for now) or this should be a topic for code review SO section?

Comment: Both of the code examples are hard to read compared to simply using `std::ranges::mismatch()` against two `std::ranges::subrange` views.

Comment: @TobySpeight, you are absolutely right and I wouldn't have even asked if ranges had execution policies which they are still missing and which I stressed in my question here. There are lots of places in the code where these bounding checks are used in sorting predicates and other places which benefit dramatically from multi-threading.

Comment: @JanSchultke, just to make you you notice my addition to the question in form of code review in the [Fast search for the longest repeating substrings in large text](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288936/fast-search-for-the-longest-repeating-substrings-in-large-text). May I ask you to join to code review to make this code more readable, manageable and clean to make decision if sentinels is, indeed, really needed here?

Comment: @WeijunZhou, the initial code in the question contained a misprint (not all variables were renamed, my bad). I've updated the question and created the [Fast search for the longest repeating substrings in large text](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288936/fast-search-for-the-longest-repeating-substrings-in-large-text) code review request for the whole code. Could you please take a look and participate, if possible, showing the way to use `std::ranges::subrange(iter, custom_sentinel)` in this case?

Comment: @TobySpeight, I've created the code review request [Fast search for the longest repeating substrings in large text](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288936/fast-search-for-the-longest-repeating-substrings-in-large-text). Can I ask you to step in with your way to implement the code?

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard container that natively supports the functionality you want. However, there is nothing stopping you from writing your own. You could (should) even use an existing container (like `std::vector`) to handle the underlying container functionality, allowing your class to focus on your "transparency" (giving your single class a single responsibility).

To me, it looks like some of the logic will be convoluted if you use iterators for everything, but it looks possible. Instead of relying on iterators and senitnels, I might give the class a function that takes two indices (possibly negative) and returns `true` if either an index is out of range or the elements at those indices are equal. The exact details would be subject to change to match your real code's requirements, but this would simulate your proposed sentinels without them occupying memory.

---

That being said, wouldn't it be simpler to move one of your conditions from the loop condition to an `if` statement? I would also move the loop itself to its own function to make the code easier to read. (I've also switched the index types from `int` to `std::size_t`. That is not essential, but I do recommend consistency between the parameter and return types.)

```cpp
std::size_t find_offset(char * text, std::size_t index1, std::size_t index2) {
    // Limit the offset so we do not read past the beginning of the array.
    auto limit = std::min(index1, index2);
    for (std::size_t offset = 0; offset <= limit; ++offset)
        if ( text[index1-offset] != text[index2-offset] )
            return offset;

    // What should happen if no match is found?
    // This matches the loop given in the question.
    return limit + 1;
}
```

Called as

```cpp
auto offset = find_offset(text, index, *(&index+line));
```

*Rule of thumb:* if you've moved the definition of your loop control variable outside your `for` statement, consider moving the loop into a function that returns where the loop ended. An extra layer of abstraction solves many problems, sometimes including readability.

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me refactor the code in this way and share it in a separate question to continue the discussion. I like the idea to replace sentinels with check function in STL style. Question: did you mean `if ( text[index1-offset] != text[index2-offset] )`? The condition should be reversed here, I guess. On the "if no match found", the `offset` value is used further in the code to make a decision based on the found (or not found if 0) sequence length.

Comment: @DamirTenishev *"The condition should be reversed here, I guess."* -- This demonstrates why it is preferable to work off of functional specs rather than code.

Comment: I've created the Code Review request [Fast search for the longest repeating substrings in large text](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288936/fast-search-for-the-longest-repeating-substrings-in-large-text), incorporating your function. Could you, please take a look at the whole code and my concerns in the request so that we could continue improvements with clean code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want sentinels, there's nothing to stop you writing a container that wraps a `std::vector` with the two extra elements (and implementing functions such as the `begin()`/`end()` family by offsetting the underlying iterators by the appropriate amount).  You'll have to forward `emplace_back()` and `erase()` and many more, but still much less work than implementing a container from scratch.

C++ doesn't provide such a container because not enough people desire it (and it can't be implemented as part of `std::vector` without incurring a cost for those that don't use it).  Also partly because there's not always a value that can't be present.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a job for containers, it sounds like a job for a custom view. Actually, `std::views::join` could do it.

Comment: Oh yes, that's much easier!

Comment: Thank you for the proposal, let me keep the "Accepted" position open so far in case of more attracting :) ideas.

Comment: @JanSchultke, yes, it would be much better if ranges/views/projections had support for execution policies. I've updated the question.